# MYSQL select count of rows that fall in a month for every month of the year

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, datetime-generation

With the table:

```
id   date_from    date_to
---------------------------
1    2010-01-01   2010-03-01
2    2010-02-07   2010-05-01
3    2010-07-05   2010-07-10
```

I am trying to return a result which has one row for each month of the year that lets me know how many rows were active in that period.

So for the above I would want the result

```
2010-01-01 1
2010-02-01 2
2010-03-01 2
2010-04-01 1
2010-05-01 1
2010-06-01 0
2010-07-01 1
2010-08-01 0
2010-09-01 0
etc...
```

I've tried grouping my MONTH(date_from) , but that doesn't return the rows with no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of times, increasing the months based on the NUMBERS.id value:

   ```
   SELECT x.*
     FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d') 
             FROM numbers n) x
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your table of data based on the time portion:

   ```
      SELECT x.ts AS timestamp,
             SUM(CASE WHEN x.ts BETWEEN y.date_from AND y.date_to THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
        FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL n.id - 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d') AS ts
                FROM numbers n) x
   LEFT JOIN TABLE y ON x.ts BETWEEN y.date_from AND y.date_to
    GROUP BY x.ts
   ```